# How to save previous timestamp to Firebase FireStore

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I want to migrate the older data from different system to firestore.

below command saves current timestamp

```
firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

I want to store older values, Is there any way available?

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to store older values"?

Comment: Yes, pass a Date object for the field that you want to be a Timestamp object.

Comment: @DougStevenson I already have some data, I want to store it as it is with datatype timestamp. Is it possible using JavaScript by any chance?

Comment: Yes, convert that data to a Date object and use that as I just described.

Comment: @DougStevenson  Thank you sir, With using Date object I succeeded, previously I was using only Date() instead of Date Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is a marker value you can use in your code to write the current server-side timestamp into a date field. If you want to store another value in a date field, you can specify the value when writing.

From the [Firebase documentation on adding data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#data_types):

```
db.collection("data").doc("one").set({
    dateField: new Date("December 10, 1815"),
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for response sir, I tried this but it stores Date using String Datatype. We can insert any timestamp using firebase console. Is it possible to Save this using JavaScript?

Comment: Thank you sir, I was using only Date() instead of new Date() so using Date object it comes possible.