# How to save Timestamp value in Cloud Firestore and perform query on it?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've followed this [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54217229/how-to-save-timestamp-in-firestore) and there is clearly said how to store the timestamp, if we user the **ServerTimestamp** annotation. However, I want to ask about other alternatives, which can later also be used to perform queries on them.

With respect to the different time libraries (before/after Java 8) we can get the timestamp as a `long` variables, or as `ZonedDateTime` object. My question is:

Can we save `ZonedDateTime` object or a `long` variable as a String and then perform queries on it, or we must use in any case **ServerTimestamp** annotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a timestamp field, and you can't use a server timestamp, you will need to either provide a regular Java Date object, or a Firebase [Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp) object.  Either of these types of values will convert to a timestamp field in the document.

When you query for the document, the field will always show up in the document snapshot as a Timestamp type object.

Comment: Okay. So only those two are accepted by Firebase? (I'm asking because articles say to avoid objects like Date, SimpleDateType, or maybe I've misunderstood it)

Comment: Just Date and Timestamp.  You will have to convert to one of those.  I suggest just giving it a try.

Comment: Thank you! I will do!

Comment: @H.Karatsanov While `java.sql.Timestamp` is a poorly designed and long outdated class (a true hack on top of the already poorly designed `java.util.Date`), the firebase `Timestamp` class is newer. I don’t know it, but I would expect that it doesn’t share the bad traits of the `java.sql` type.

Comment: @OleV.V. you're right. But since Firebase works only with Date, we need to take the LocalDateTime(ThreeTen.., java.time) and then parse it to Date, in order for Firebase to accept it. I will write the answer for it with code later

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. As you know when we're dealing with Time in Android, we need to pay attention to the different APIs i.e. APIs before API 26 and after that. There are many articles for this topic in Stackoverflow, but generalized, before *Android 8 (Oreo, API 26)* we need to use the library **ThreeTenABP** and after Android 8 we need to use **java.time**.

An implementation looks like this:

```
private Date getCurrentDate(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            return Date.from(Instant.now());
        } else {
            AndroidThreeTen.init(this);
            return DateTimeUtils.toDate(org.threeten.bp.Instant.now());
        }
    }
```

Of course, you can use `LocalDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime` etc.

*Firebase* expects `Date` object, or you can use the `@ServerTimestamp` annotation and provide no parameter in the constructor of your model. Firebase will then create the timestamp when request for saving data comes to it. Like this

```
//When you provide Date 
class SomeClass {
   private String someAttribute;
   private Date someDate;
   ...
   public SomeClass(String someAttribute, Date someDate, ...){
     this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
     this.someDate = someDate;

   }
}

//When you don't provide Date 
class SomeClass {
   private String someAttribute;
   private @ServerTimestamp Date someDate;
   ...
   public SomeClass(String someAttribute, ...){
     this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
    ...
   }
}
```

(In may case I needed the Date object when I start an activity, but a request to the server may happen even after 2-3 hours. That's why `@ServerTimestamp` was inefficient for me.)

The retrieving happens in the same way. Create a model class, or use `HashMap` (your choice) but the type must be `Date`. It holds almost every kind of information according to date and time (time zone, the time is even up to microseconds etc).

Most of the time, the user wants to see only a date and a time in form of *hours:minutes*.
You can use `DateTimeFormatter` and provide the pattern which you want (there are plenty of standards). In my case I use it in this way:

```
private String formatDate(Date date){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            java.time.LocalDateTime ldt = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
            java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter dtf = java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
            return ldt.format(dtf);
        } else {
            LocalDateTime ldt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()).atZone(org.threeten.bp.ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
            DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
            return ldt.format(dtf);
        }
    }
```

As you see the method expects a `Date` object (what you retrieve from Firebase). Then it will remove most of the irrelevant data (in my case) and return you only the date and the time in the specified format.

(Note: in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318109/is-it-possible-to-use-java-8-for-android-development/43237601?noredirect=1#comment110915582_43237601) where **UPDATE 2020/01/17** is, a colleague points that with Android Studio 4.0 we can use Java 8 in older APIs as well (like in my case - API 21), but I didn't dig into the topic concrete. You can check it also :)